# Android: How to populate a layout with different string value files?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-listview

I'm designing an app that holds contact and menu information for about 15 different restaurants. All the code i have done so far works as I would like it to, but I'm having trouble with the theory of where to go next.

I have a layout designed for the restaurant activity, I want to use this as a base layout for all the restaurants.

I want to have a string value file for each restaurant, and when a place is selected via the spinner I have on the main activity page, or via an individual image button, the restaurant activity is started and the base layout is populated with the corresponding value file.

I have trawled the internet looking for a solution or a tutorial for this but haven't found anything so far.

If anyone could give me a nod in the right direction with regard to my theory on how to implement this, I'll manage the coding.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, there is one solution right in your post.

Comment: I have tried this. In the different value files for each restaurant, I have tried using the same String @id/ref for the elements of the layout, but gives me an error for duplicate values. Eg A Large Textview with the id @+id/txtName to display the name of the Resturant at the top of the activity_Rest. In the a.xml value file I have <string name="txtName">RestA</string> and in b.xml I have <string name="txtName">RestB</string>. Then I get the error. Obviously I'm doing wrong somewhere. I just can't figure it out.

Comment: A line of code is worth ten thousand words.

Comment: Dude, I don't know where to start with this, hence asking the question in words. If I had code, I would have put it up.

Comment: You say the code you have done so far works, so there must be code. You are talking about errors, but you show no error log. You name no concrete coding problem. But one thing... the values folder is not for this kind of data. Put your data into your assets folder and read it from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a string file in your project value folder so you can place content of any resturant in it and when you want start resturant activity you can use putextra method for send of content of resturant and in oncreate method of resturant activity you should set content to your textviews